# Running logstash forwarder as a daemon service

Tags: bash, redhat, daemon

I found this article who explain how to make a start stop service ; http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html

And so I wrote this :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 3 80 20
# description: boop-logstash-forwarder
#
# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Start the service

LOGSTASH_FORWARDER="/logiciels/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder"
LF_CONF="/appli/projects/BOOP-LOGSTASH-FORWARDER/logstash-forwarder.conf"
SERVICE_NAME="boop-logstash-forwarder"

start() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Starting $SERVICE_NAME: "
        $LOGSTASH_FORWARDER -config=$LF_CONF &
        ### Create the lock file ###
        touch /var/lock/subsys/$SERVICE_NAME
        success $"$SERVICE_NAME startup"
        echo
}
# Restart the service
stop() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Stopping $SERVICE_NAME: "
        killproc $SERVICE_NAME
        ### Now, delete the lock file ###
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$SERVICE_NAME
        echo
}
### main logic ###
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status $SERVICE_NAME
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

I have 2 problem with this, first the logstash forwarder is taking control of the console an is very verbose, should I in the launch command redirect it's output to a file?

second and biggest problem the stop command won't work, I get :

```
Stopping looping-logstash-forwarder:                       [FAILED]
```

Did I do something wront in the script?

Thanks.

ps : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9

Comment: did you write `killproc` or is that something in `/usr/bin/` (sorry don't have a RHELS to work with). Seems like the problem must be there. What happens if you run that from the cmd line? Or assuming that is a script, execute it's steps manually from the cmd-line to see what the problem is. Good luck.

Comment: kill proc is defined in /etc/init.d/functions and imported in the script so it should work.

Comment: but it sure seems like it isn't working. So I would want to know why. If you have another theory or path to explore to resolve this, then  you should follow it ELSE make sure `killproc` is working as expected. You could do `if killproc "$serviceName" ; then echo error running killproc 1>&2 ; exit fi` to confirm it is killproc that is generating the `[FAILED]` text. Good luck.

Comment: yup, it says error running killproc, but no reason is displayed

Comment: OK, so are you going to give up? Now you know for certain there is a problem in killproc. You'll have to isolate the exact line inside of that script that is erroring out, and examine the arguments being passed in. I would copy `killproc` to /tmp, edit and add `set -vxe ; set PS4='${LINENO} #'` at the top, and run `/tmp/killproc "$serviceName"` and see where it stops and what are the arguments being passed in. I'm guessing that some how your "$serviceName" is not really what you think it is and can't match against any running process names. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not giving up, I'm going around, I modifing it to store the pid in a file and use kill in the stop command.

I'm going to try what you wrote tho, to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Great, yep, storing a PID seems like a good idea, but confirm that the value stored is the same as the running process. Sometime sub-shells are created that mask the real PID for the process of interest . Good luck.

Comment: And sorry for the chiding. I guess we have different communication styles! ;-> Good luck.

Comment: no worries, well the version who uses kill works, time to dive into this killproc mystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working vesion who uses kill instead of killproc :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 3 80 20
# description: boop-logstash-forwarder
#
# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Start the service

LOGSTASH_FORWARDER="/logiciels/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder"
LF_CONF="/appli/projects/BOOP-LOGSTASH-FORWARDER/logstash-forwarder.conf"
LOGFILE="/appli/projects/BOOP-LOGSTASH-FORWARDER/logstash-forwarder.log"
PIDFILE="/appli/projects/BOOP-LOGSTASH-FORWARDER/logstash-forwarder.pid"
SERVICE_NAME="boop-logstash-forwarder"

blockUntilFileExist () {
    while ! [[ -f "$1" ]] ; do
        echo "Waiting for creation of $1"
        sleep 1
    done
}

start() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Starting $SERVICE_NAME: "
        $LOGSTASH_FORWARDER -config=$LF_CONF > $LOGFILE 2>&1 & echo $! > $PIDFILE
        blockUntilFileExist $PIDFILE
        success $"$SERVICE_NAME startup"
        echo
}

stop() {
        initlog -c "echo -n Stopping $SERVICE_NAME: "
        if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            echo "process with pid contained in $PIDFILE does not exist"
            exit
        else
            echo "killing process with pid contained in $PIDFILE"
            kill `cat $PIDFILE`
        fi
        echo
}
### main logic ###
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status $SERVICE_NAME
        ;;
  restart|reload|condrestart)1
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```